# How to make internal link to go to another component's ID element - Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-routing

**Problem Statement**

I cannot seem to use an internal link in the `<a>` tag to go to another component's specific section by HTML ID.

---

**What I've tried**

- I went to this site: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp and found nothing related to what I am doing.
- Also, I went to this site https://www.yourhtmlsource.com/text/internallinks.html and found the thing that is related to my problem. The part is called: "*Linking to parts of other documents*" and this doesn't seem to work: `<a href="http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/text/internallinks.html#section-names">`. It basically links to another document and it goes to a specific section of that site, but alas, it does not work for me.

---

**My Code**

This is the page I am linking from:

```
<a href="../products/products.component.html#backToTopBtn"><button mat-raised-button class="productsServicesBtn">Products
      <br>Services</button></a>
```

This is the page I want to link to:

```
<body>
  <button mat-raised-button id="backToTopBtn">Back to Top</button>
</body>
```

**Please Note**: These are two different Angular components.

---

**Explanation Of Code**

As you can see, I am using what the second website has told me to do inside the `href` with the HTML ID at the end of the link to tell the browser which section to go to. It does not work.

**FYI**, the ID at the end is called a "*fragment identifier*".

---

**Expected Results**

The "*internal*" link opens up the other page and goes to the specific section which I mentioned.

---

**Actual Results**

The link does nothing and does not go anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you should set up your links using the `routerLink` directive.

```
<a routerLink="/products">
  <button mat-raised-button class="productsServicesBtn">
    Products<br>Services
  </button>
</a>
```

This is assuming you have set up your route. You should read up on [routing](https://angular.io/guide/router) if not.

```
  { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent }
```

Secondly, you specify the fragment via the `fragment` input of the routerLink directive:

```
<a routerLink="/products" fragment="backToTopBtn">
  <button mat-raised-button class="productsServicesBtn">
    Products<br>Services
  </button>
</a>
```

Finally, you need to enable anchor scrolling when you import the router module, as scrolling to the fragment is disabled by default:

```
imports: [
  RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent }
  ], { anchorScrolling: 'enabled' })
]
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/router-template-4uagmq

Comment: you should also mention `<a name="...">` link with a name in your answer

Comment: @Andrei The OP contains the target element with the id specified, so the poster already understood how to create a fragment, the question was about how to navigate to it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I added the fragment

You should not link to `./products.component.html` as it does not exist at runtime (in the browser).

you should link to a route using routerLink

```
 <a routerLink="/product" fragment="backToTopBtn">services</a>
```

check angular docs [Routing and navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not solve my problem. The problem is not routing to the page, it's routing to a *specific section* of the page.

Comment: add a "fragment identifier" ?

Comment: use the fragment directive, i just edited my response